# How to Capitalize the first letter of existing GitHub repository?

Tags: github, repository

Situation is:

Currently, I have a repository name **phimpme-iOS**. I want to capitalize the first letter of the repository, **Phimpme-iOS**.

When I change the name in *Settings > Options > Repository Name*, it cannot be changed and it is showing -

> The repository Phimpme-iOS already exists on this account

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User names and repository names are case-insensitive at Github: `phimpme-iOS` is the same as `Phimpme-iOS`; that is, from Github PoV you're trying to rename the repo to an equivalent name.

Try a completely different name — `xxx`, for example — and then rename it once more to `Phimpme-iOS`.

Comment: This was fixed in the meantime btw.
You can now change the case of your repo. Again, nothing will break, since it never really mattered to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your repository to something completely different (e.g. "foo") and then name it back to  the original name with the desired capitalization.